# uniform has a meaning of rational number?

Tags: word-meaning

Upon reading the python documentation, I encountered  `random.uniform` [random — Generate pseudo-random numbers — Python 3.7.3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html)

> random.uniform(a, b)¶
>   Return a random floating point number N such that a <= N <= b for a <= b and b <= N <= a for b < a.

The end-point value b may or may not be included in the range depending on floating-point rounding in the equation a + (b-a) * random().

Corresponding to the integers, random.uniform here is floating number of rational number.

I looked up various dictionaries but did not find meaning of number in 'uniform"

Does uniform has the meaning of rational number as jargon in any disciplines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Uniform" here refers to the fact that the numbers should be uniformly distributed between `a` and `b`, and not just numbers that happen to be integers.

"Uniform" is a mathematical term here; see [Wikipedia: Uniform distribution (continuous)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)):

> In probability theory and statistics, the continuous uniform distribution or rectangular distribution is a family of symmetric probability distributions such that for each member of the family, all intervals of the same length on the distribution's support are equally probable. The support is defined by the two parameters, a and b, which are its minimum and maximum values.
>
> [image]

Comment: your answer deserve one thousand times ty. thank you.